# Determine user activity in iOS?

Tags: ios, geolocation, accelerometer

How to determine user motion activity (walking, running, in a vehicle, in a car, etc)?

I found that `CMMotionActivityManager` class  doing this, but it's `isActivityAvailable` will return true ONLY on the M7 equipped devices: iPhone5S, iPad mini with retina, iPad Air.

So what is the right way to do that in non M7 equipped devices ? 
Or may be you know any third-party libs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find answer to my question , so I decided to write my own lib that will work on all iOS devices and no need M7 chip.

Here is the link to github repo, maybe it can help someone.

https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/SOMotionDetector